# How do you create a Radio Button column in Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms

Currently using PowerApps to make a form, and I'd like for a few of the inputs to be radio buttons like so:

[image]

But then in the linked SharePoint List, I cant seem to find a radio button column type:

[image]

I get that I can manually add a function that sends the text field to a column, but I'd like to do everything natively if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a **Choice** column type in SharePoint. Which can be used as a radio buttons:

[image]

You can see the **Display choices using:** setting under **More options**.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that option. Thanks a lot